# Camera's Surface view translucency is not activated after home is pressed

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I have a camera app that sets the camera's SurfaceView to translucent so that object/image over it can be seen and it works perfectly but when home is pressed and onResume is called the translucency is gone and the object/image that is suppose to be over it is now under camera`s surface view. I would be happy if some one helps thanks.

Comment: The SurfaceView lifecycle isn't quite the same as the Activity lifecycle, so you have to be careful about how you initialize things.  See https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity

Comment: The detailed description here: _[How SurfaceHolder callbacks are related to Activity lifecycle?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13671391/192373)_

Comment: Thank you guys. I have another problem if you can help me out with this I would be very glad. Heres the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237407/decoder-for-byte-data-returned-by-onpreviewframebyte-data-camera-camera